# Finding the radius of convergence for $\sum n^p z^n$ (Proof Verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

**Goal:** Find the radius of convergence for the following complex power series:

$$
\sum n^p z^n
$$

**Attempt:**

1. We have by Hadamard's formula for the radius of convergence that the complex power series $\sum a_n z^n$ converges if $|z| < R$ s.t.

   $$
   R = \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} |a_n|^{1/n}}
   $$
2. Then we here have that $a_n = n^p$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. Then applying Hadamard's formula we obtain that

   $$
   R = \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} |n^p|^{1/n}}
   $$
4. Then since

   $$
   \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} |n^p|^{1/n} = 1
   $$

   no matter the value of $p$, we have that $R = 1$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct.

Here you can also use the more elementary approach using the d'Alembert lemma:
there is convergence of the series as soon as

$$
1 > \lim\frac {|(n+1)^pz^{n+1}|} {|n^pz^p|} = 
\lim \left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^p |z|
= |z|
$$
and divergence as soon as
$$
1 < \lim\frac {|(n+1)^pz^{n+1}|} {|n^pz^p|} 
= |z|
$$
so $R = 1 $.